# the header is being ignored

Tags: php, header

```
<?
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$email = $_COOKIE['email'];
$password = $_COOKIE['password'];
header('Location: ../');
// I tell it to redirect...
$cookie_expires = time() + 60*60*24;
$cookie_path = '/';
$cookie_name = 'temporary';
$cookie_value = 'Your account was deleted.';
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_expires, $cookie_path);
// ...but the cookie is set!
?>
<!-- Why? -->
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Which cookie is set, and why are you expecting it not to be?

Comment: What is the difference: return, die and exit?

Comment: @Delirium tremens: There is no difference.  The docs for die even say `die — Equivalent to exit()`

Comment: I think exit/die might have effects on shutdown functions that return wont

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Script execution continues after setting a `Location:` header (or any other call to `header()`, for that matter).  If you want the redirect to happen immediately, without the rest of the script executing, `return;` or `die;` immediately after you call `header()`.

Comment: +1 And i would also set the cookie before sending the redirecting header.

Comment: About 90 mins completely flummoxed... But so obvious when you understand this. I don't normally do "Thanks" s as it is frowned upon but in this case I cannot restrain myself - THANKS

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are sent as part of the header.  The whole header is evaluated (including setting the cookie) then the browser redirects.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
header('Location: ../');
exit();
```

The page (including your headers) only gets sent after 'all' your php is executed (unless you tell it to stop with die() or exit());

Answer (score 0):

have you got error reporting turned off, that would help you out with the syntax error and is always worth doing in a dev environment.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

EDIT: there was a syntax error with a double semi-colon but that seems to have been corrected

you also need to call `exit()` after your header or script execution will not stop and the cookie will be sete